# Create multiple txt (Text_01.txt --- Text_50.txt) file with the file name and current date stamp

Tags: windows, powershell

Could somebody help me to write a script in Powershell to 
create 50 .txt files with date and the name of the file in every file?
And then rename them and add the new name and date to the second line?

Comment: Wow. This actually got 3 answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you are a bit stressing the goodwill of people answering,
and not any upvote yet.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\11\19\SO_53381881.ps1
$DestPath = $ENV:TMP
1..50 | ForEach-Object {
    $Now = [datetime]::Now
    $NewName = "{0}\{1:00}.txt" -f $DestPath,$_
    New-Item -Path $NewName -ItemType 'File' -Force -Value "$NewName $Now`n" |Out-Null
}

## output current content
gci $Env:TMP\[0-9][0-9].txt |sort name| gc


## rename by getting current numbers with a regex and subtracting 1
Get-ChildItem $Env:TMP\[0-9][0-9].txt |sort name|
  Where-Object BaseName -match "^(?<Number>\d{2})$"| ForEach-Object {
    $NewName = "{0}\{1:00}{2}" -f $_.DirectoryName,([int]$Matches.Number -1),$_.Extension
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
    Add-Content -Path $NewName -Value "$NewName $Now`n"
  }
## output new current content
gci $Env:TMP\[0-9][0-9].txt | gc
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
1..50 | ForEach-Object {New-Item  -Path "C:\temp\$($_.ToString("00"))_$(Get-Date -Format 'yy-mm-dd').txt"}
```

or if you want to write stuff to the file, and have something more readable

```
foreach ($N in 1..50){
    $FilePath = "C:\temp"
    $FileName = "Text_$($N.ToString("00")).txt"
    New-Item -Path "$FilePath\$FileName"
    $Date = Get-Date 
    Add-Content -Path "$FilePath\$FileName" -Value $FileName
    Add-Content -Path "$FilePath\$FileName" -Value $Date.ToString("hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yy")
}
```

note you will want to fiddle with the $Date.ToString() bit to allow for reigonal diferences.

Comment: right I changed it then

Comment: would it be possible to rename all files for example Text_01 --> Text_00 and so on and then add a new line to the file with the new file name and new date?
many of thanks

Answer (score 0):

here's an alternate method. it breaks out most of the $Vars as individual items to make the process a tad more clear ... [*grin*]

```
$DestDir = $env:TEMP
$FNamePrefix = 'Text_'
$FNameExt = '.txt'

# if you want the file content to be all on one line, remove this $Var from the "Set-Content" line
$NewLine = [environment]::NewLine

$FileCount = 5
foreach ($Count in 1..$FileCount)
    {
    $TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
    # create a left-padded 2 digit number string
    $Number = '{0:D2}' -f $Count
    $FileName = -join ($FNamePrefix, $Number, $FNameExt)
    $FullFileName = Join-Path -Path $DestDir -ChildPath $FileName

    # this will create the file or overwrite any pre-existing one
    #    the "-Value" stuff will be in the file
    #    to put the info all on one line use the following for the "-Value" info
    #    ""$TimeStamp; $FileName"
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $FullFileName -Value "$TimeStamp$NewLine$FileName" -Force
    }
```

there is no on-screen output. the content of the 1st file is ...

```
2018-11-19 15:00:51
Text_01.txt
```

the name of that file is `Text_01.txt`. [*grin*]

Comment: would it be possible to rename all files for example Text_01 --> Text_00 and so on and then add a new line to the file with the new file name and new date? many of thanks

Comment: @XebatRammo - what changed? i thot you wanted to create the files with the create date/time and the file name in the file. now ... is this a different thing?

Comment: well am trying to create about 50 text files and then rename them without losing any line in the file.

Comment: @XebatRammo - rename them how? subtract one from the digits on the end? this step was not mentioned in your OP ... [*grin*]

Comment: @ Lee_Dailey i know am sorry am very new here :/
as i mentioned before am trying to create 50 .txt file with the current date and then rename them but am trying to add the new name and the new date to every file.
i'll appreciate it if you could help me with this

Comment: @XebatRammo - please go back to your OP & add a clear, concise set of steps that you wan done. the getting the filename &B the date info ADDED to the file would be done with `Add-Content`. renaming the file would be done with `Rename-Item`. getting the list of files would be done with `Get-ChildItem`.